# cellular data network firebase cloud messaging not receiving notification of data messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had set up Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in standard manner.
It works good when mobile connected to internet via WiFi
But after I switch to Mobile (Cellular) data internet, close app, close mobile then the FCM stop to work, since other similar Apps ( facebook messanger, etc. ) continue to receiving data.

**Manifest:**

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />



    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".NotificationDismissedReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />
```

**Other classes:**

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService

Same way as described in google Firebase Cloud Messaging documentations.

What happens ? what should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Share logs and complete code where you are initializing FCM.

Comment: I use exactly google Firebase Quickstarts for Android examples:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Messaging: 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

Comment: Could be that your mobile operator is blocking something? Whatsapp and Messenger sometimes have special contracts with the operators. Could you try a different operator?

Comment: I am not sure, but seems that you are right.

cases for one operator I had tested:
1. switch on cellular data (phone is on) - messages receiving
2. switch off phone - messages not receiving
3. switch on phone again - messages not receiving

second operator cases:
1. switch on cellular data (phone is on) - messages receiving
2. switch off phone - messages not receiving
3. switch on phone again - messages start to receiving with delay

so for second operator FCM works little bit better.